# How to get max values in a datatable?

Tags: datatables

**My datatable:**

[image]

**I want to get the maximum value from the table, and my expectations are like this :**

1. Nagrog  0.601
2. Babakan 0.524
3. Dampit  0.518

**code for datatables :**

```
$("#tabelkriteria").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    scrollY : true,
    scrollX : true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    responsive: true,
    ajax: '{!! route('admin.topsis.matrix_keputusan_ternormalisasi') !!}',
    order:[0,'desc'],
    columns:[
        {data:'id', name: 'id'},
        {data:'nama', name: 'nama'},
        {data:'r_makan',name:'r_makan'},
        {data:'r_infeksi',name:'r_infeksi'},
        {data:'r_sanitasi',name:'r_sanitasi'},
        {data:'r_asuh',name:'r_asuh'},
        {data:'r_pangan',name:'r_pangan'},
        {data:'r_miskin',name:'r_miskin'},
        {data:'r_pendidikan', name:'r_pendidikan'}                        
    ]         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Going through your problem, you could do something like.

[Instances](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Instances)

You could have a field which holds the maximum value which can be computed using javascript methods.

```js
function Data ( f1, f2, f3, f4 ) {
    this.f1 = f1;
    this.f2 = f2;
    this.f3 = f3;
    this.f4 = f4;
    this._f5 = Math.max(f1,f2,f3,f4);
 
    this.f5 = function () {
        return this._f5;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to iterate over each row of data in your table and extract the maximum value:

```
table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
    var data = this.data();
    // get a subset of the row data, excluding the first cell
    // if the values are stored as strings, map then to numbers.
    // If they are already formatted as numbers, you don't need
    // the map() function:
    var values = data.slice(1).map(Number);
    // the ... operator expands the array into values for the 
    // max() function to operate on:
    console.log( data[0] + ': ' + Math.max( ...values ) );
} );
```

Here is the code used with a sample DataTable:

```
<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

<table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value One</th>
                <th>Value Two</th>
                <th>Value Three</th>
                <th>Value Four</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>first item</td>
                <td>1.2345</td>
                <td>2.3456</td>
                <td>3.4567</td>
                <td>4.5678</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>second item</td>
                <td>9.8765</td>
                <td>3.5454</td>
                <td>4.2627</td>
                <td>8.2354</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>third item</td>
                <td>8.5678</td>
                <td>3.5601</td>
                <td>0.0121</td>
                <td>1.3254</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable(  );

    table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
        var data = this.data();
        var values = data.slice(1).map(Number);
        console.log( data[0] + ': ' + Math.max( ...values ) );
    } );

} );

</script>

</body>
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

In this example, the results are only displayed in the browser's console - but you can adapt this to however you need to use the data.

WARNING: This is a basic solution. There is no error handling (e.g. if you have non-numeric data, for example).

**UPDATE:**

Based on additional information from the OP, here is how the above logic can be integrated into a `drawCallback` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {

        "drawCallback": function () {
            this.api().rows().every( function ( ) {
                var data = this.data();
                var values = data.slice(1).map(Number);
                console.log( data[0] + ': ' + Math.max( ...values ) );
            } );
          }

    } );

} );
```

This is the same basic logic as in my first example, but now we get the row data for the table by calling the `api()` function:

```
this.api().rows().every( function ( ) { ... } );
```

Comment: I got the data from the calculation in the controller, after I tried your solution an error occurred in data.slice(). map (Number)

Comment: What is the specific error message? The `data` needs to come from the function I provided: `table.rows().every(...)`. Otherwise `var data = this.data();` is probably null. And your data table needs to be assigned: `var table = ..` also.

Comment: [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62690890/typeerror-data-slice-is-not-function)

Comment: You define `var table` - but then you try to use `table` from inside where it is defined. That is not possible. In my example, the table variable is first defined in one JavaScript statement, and then it is used in a following JavaScript statement.

Comment: I have tried what you showed, but nothing happened to the console

Comment: OK - understood. I have added an alternative approach, which uses the `drawCallback` from your other question.